# drag scrolling Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I am new to Silverlight and I am looking to create a StackPanel that scrolls by dragging it up or down, similarly to how PDF readers work.  I did not know if there was anything built in or if I would have to create my own based on mouse down and up.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, just catch MouseMove when LMB is down and change scrolling offset by horizontal difference between last and current points.